# Google API Client, calling the built API with dot in parameter name

Tags: python, google-api-client

Im on Google App Engine, I try to call the a specific method of the Monitoring API via Google API Client. When I call the `timeSeries.list` with `interval.startTime` then the error is `SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression`. When I replace `interval.startTime` and `interval.EndTime` with `interval=intervalobj` the error is:

```
File "/base/data/home/apps/e~bwm2-bgi/scaler:
scaling-readmon.412218217025616715/lib/googleapiclient/discovery.py", 
line 716, in method raise TypeError
('Got an unexpected keyword argument "%s"' % name) 
TypeError: Got an unexpected keyword argument "interval"
```

I used the Compute API in the same manner like `interval=intervalobl`and it worked. Any tip is appreciated.

CODE:

```
import webapp2
import logging
from google.appengine.ext import vendor
vendor.add('lib')
from google.appengine.api import app_identity
from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

monitoring = discovery.build('monitoring','v3', credentials=GoogleCredentials.get_application_default())
class Scaler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
        def post(self):
                '''
                req = monitoring.projects().metricDescriptors().list(name='projects/PROJ')
                res = req.execute()
                logging.info(res)
                '''
                intervalobj = {
                        'startTime': '2018-08-10T11:01:23.045123456Z',
                        'endTime': '2018-08-10T11:01:23.045123456Z'
                }

                res = monitoring.projects().timeSeries().list(
                        name = 'projects/bwm2-bgi',
                        filter = 'metric.type="appengine.googleapis.com/http/server/response_style_count"',
                        interval.startTime = '2018-08-10T11:01:23.045123456Z',
                        interval.endTime = '2018-08-28T11:01:23.045123456Z').execute()
                logging.info(res)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
        ('/scaler', Scaler)
], debug=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `interval_startTime` and `interval_endTime` worked in place of the `interval.startTime` and `interval.endTime` for me.

```
request = monitor.projects().timeSeries().list(name=project_name,
                                        interval_startTime='2019-03-19T06:00:00.045123456Z',
                                        interval_endTime='2019-03-19T07:00:00.045123456Z', 
                                        filter='metric.type="appengine.googleapis.com/http/server/response_style_count"')
```

I believe setting a point interval with interval.endTime is used when specifying points with the monitoring_v3.MetricServiceClient TimeSeries but not with the discovery resource.